# Merge multiple document libraries into one

Tags: 2013, document-library, merge

I need some help to solve a problem. I do not know how to move forward from here.

We have about 15-20 different document libraries where different departments submit their projects/files. Then we have a management team who wants to see the progress of all projects/files without having to go into each department.

Is there any good solution to merge all libraries into a single librarie? Or somehow present the data.

Comment: Are you using Content types in those libraries? If the project status report is a Content type then it might be fairly simple to create a portfolio overview using search

Comment: Yes, I will use content types in those libraries.  Do you have any links to how that might look?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a search based approach might be an option. Set up at search resultat that only includes documents from those libraries, using Path and add a refiner and search box.

If each project space/folder contains a document of type "project status" you should be able to roll up the content as per https://youtu.be/KAaYKe9HaDU

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't merge all of your department's document libraries in to one document library!  Since there must be a reason behind the existing structure.  For example, two reasons:

1. security/access - if people have read/write access to documents in their department, that is fine.  However, if you use only one document library, the people in e.g. Sales will be able to edit HR and Finance's documents!
2. document lifecycle - for managing and expiring documents.  This is much easier to do when document are split out in to different document libraries.

You'll need to find another way to cope with your management's requirements.  The departments can either go to the management site to report on their results or you find a way of using 'look-up' columns to do this.  The standard Sharepoint 'look-up' columns are insufficient for inter-site collection work.  Does each department have a separate 'site collection'?  If so, then I would recommend [third party Sparqube look-up columns](http://www.sparqube.com/SharePoint-Lookup-Column/) - I don't work for Sparqube.

The 'look-up extra' column type means you could look up 'project name' and 'progress' fields from different lists/document libraries in different site collections.

Another method would be to use CQWP ([Content Query Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/when-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-or-the-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929)) to build a sort of dashboard for management to use.  The queries you define would display the relevant content for management to review.

Comment: Based on the information I received, I can probably add all the libraries under the same site and arrange unique permissions for each library. Their description was that it should look like excel. Where all users fill in their spreadsheet and then there is a document compiling all of them.
My first thought was to use 'look-up', but since they want all the data from all the columns, it felt like the wrong way to go. but you think it could be a good solution?
I have not worked so much with CQWP.  I'll read a bit about it and see if it can be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but we use Metashare. It allows you to search on metadata as we as normal filenames and file content. Nice easy way rather than duplicating sites.